# Is there a specific term for the Builder pattern where each method returns `this`?

Tags: design-patterns

I know this is the Builder pattern, but it's a modified form of it. Whereas the Wikipedia article on Builder pattern gives the example:

```
pizzaBuilder.createNewPizzaProduct();
pizzaBuilder.buildDough();
pizzaBuilder.buildSauce();
pizzaBuilder.buildTopping();
Pizza p = pizzaBuilder.getPizza();
```

**Is there a specific name for the modified Builder pattern which looks like:**

```
Pizza p = pizzaBuilder.createNewPizzaProduct().buildDough().buildSauce().buildTopping();
```

---

This is best seen in the jQuery library, where you can do something like:

```
$('li.item-a').parent().css('background-color', 'red');
```

Where each method, including the initial $(), returns a jQuery object which typically represents a set of page elements, and each method operates on that set in some way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've seen this called a **Fluent Builder** several places.

This makes a lot of sense, since it's basically a combination of a [Fluent Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) and the [Builder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) design pattern.

Comment: That's a perfect name (it communicates exactly what it is) +1

Comment: I agree, that does sound like the perfect name. Not only that, but I'd never heard of the term "Fluent interface" before, so I will go read more about other fluent techniques!

Answer (score 3):

In C++, it is called ([at least by one site](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.18)) "Named Parameter Idiom".

Answer (score 3):

It can be called a [Fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface):

> In software engineering, a fluent interface (as first coined by Eric Evans and Martin Fowler) is a way of implementing an object oriented API in a way that aims to provide for more readable code.
>
> A fluent interface is normally implemented by using method chaining to relay the instruction context of a subsequent call (but a fluent interface entails more than just method chaining)

Answer (score 3):

I would call the technique "method chaining".

(pretty much in accordance with [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining)...)

And yes, method chaining can be used to build fluent interfaces.