# builder pattern alternative

Tags: design-patterns

I was reading about the benefits of the builder pattern here: http://drdobbs.com/java/208403883?pgno=2

I was wondering about the viability of the following, which seems simpler.

```
public class NutritionFactParams {
    private int servingSize;
    private int servings;
    private int fat_ = 0;
    private int sodium_ = 0;
    NutritionFactParams(int servingSize, int servings) {
        this.servingSize = servingSize;
        this.servings = servings;
    }
    NutritionFactParams fat(int fat) {
        this.fat_ = fat;
        return this;
    }
    NutritionFactParams sodium(int sodium) {
        this.sodium_ = sodium;
        return this;
    }
}

public class NutritionFacts {
    public NutritionFacts(NutritionFactParams params) {
        // copy values across, or store NutritionFactParams as member
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        NutritionFacts n = new NutritionFacts(new NutritionFactParams(1,2).fat(23).soduim(10));
    }
}
```

This is basically the builder pattern, except that the NutritionFacts constructor is public not private, we don't have a static Builder class inside of NutritionFacts, and there is no build() method on the builder. There's no alternate or default constructor so you can't build NutritionFacts without first constructing a NutritionFactsParams.

Comment: BTW, the (slow-loading) DDJ article is just [Effective Java, Item 2](http://books.google.com/books?id=Ft8t0S4VjmwC&lpg=PR1&dq=editions%3AZZOiqZQIbRMC&pg=PA11#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is not big, but there is one important differences i can think of:

If you use builder, the client code does not need to know what Impl you actually return on build() meaning that, you have flexibility to return different Impls depending on the configuration (builder). On the other hand, using constructor, the client have to explicitly create the Impl.

Comment: if a factory is introduced that takes a param object you achieve the benefit of returning different impls.

Comment: You can do same thing in many ways. The builder is factory+configuration in one class. See: http://dadraraghu.blog.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/00/03/05/16/3051643/files/design-patterns/relationship-in-dp.jpg

Answer (score 3):

The builder pattern is especially useful when you want to create immutable objects but avoid contructors with many arguments.

The pattern you're using basically just a [fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface#Java). Applications of the builder pattern often *use* a fluent interface.

See also:

- [Is there a specific term for the Builder pattern where each method returns `this`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2930106/is-there-a-specific-term-for-the-builder-pattern-where-each-method-returns-this)

---

If you don't like the extra code overhead of using the builder pattern, have a look at [make-builder](http://code.google.com/p/make-builder/).

Comment: Both versions support immutability and no-long-constructor

Comment: I had first seen the pattern proposed for c++ as a way to achieve something similar to named arguments that exists in other languages.

Comment: @Matt Ball make-builder link isn't working, can you give some alternative link for that?